# HttpClient await hangs on PostAsync with async void method

Tags: c#, oauth, windows-phone-8, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I'm still trying to wrap my head around async and I'm wondering why the following code is causing a deadlock. My use case is this: I have a service interface which attempts to abstract how the service is implemented. One of the services is an OAuth based web-service. The service interface has a method `Connect()` which anyone using the interface must do prior to using it.

On my client side I create my concrete service object and call `Connect()` in my view constructor (this is a prototype, so I'm just trying to get a proof of concept going). In the OAuth-based service, the connect call requires retrieving an access token, so it (attempts) to do this asynchronously. This `Connect()` call never returns, though, and the application is deadlocked (but the UI is active). I'm guessing I'm messing up and trying to synchronously use my client somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

**Control**

```
public class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _webService = new OAuthBasedWebService();
        _webService.ShowAuthorizationPage += _webService_ShowAuthorizationPage; // this is defined on the concrete object -- i know, bad design
        _webService.Connect();
    }
}
```

**OAuth based webservice**

```
public class OAuthBasedWebService()
{
    private OAuthWrapper _wrapper;

    public async void Connect()
    {
        var uri = await _wrapper.GetAuthorizationUri();
        OnShowAuthorizationPage(uri);
    }
}

internal class OAuthWrapper
{
    public async Task<Uri> GetAuthorizationUri()
    {
        var uri = await _consumer.GetAuthorizationUriAsync();
        return uri;
    }
}

internal class OAuthConsumer
{
    public async Task<Uri> GetAuthorizationUriAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = "webservicebaseaddress";
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new []
            {
                CreateParameter("oauth_consumer_key", "consumerkey"),
                CreateParameter("oauth_consumer_secret", "consumersecret")
                // etc., etc.
            });

            var response = await client.PostAsync("/method_path", content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            // parse authorization uri from responseContent
            return authorizationUri;
        }
    }
}
```

I know the design needs a little work but I'm trying to figure out why this is deadlocking. I'm guessing it is because `_webService.Connect()` is not being called asynchronously but I also cannot `await` that because it doesn't return anything and the rest of the program doesn't depend on it.

Comment: I think you'll find that actually `Connect` returns pretty much *immediately* - because it's an async method. Unfortunately it's an async method returning `void`, which is generally a bad idea. Have you put break points or diagnostics in `GetAuthorizationUriAsync` to find out how far it actually gets?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "deadlock" if the UI is still responsive. Does `GetAuthorizationUriAsync` return? (BTW, I have some [tips on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) for avoiding `async void` in constructors).

Comment: `GetAuthorizationUriAsync()` gets to the first `await`. It never gets to the second one.

Comment: So this is weird, but the calls go through if I don't set `BaseAddress` and instead set the request url to be "webservicebaseaddress/method_path".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are using a event here, if the problem was just because you couldn't make the constructor "async" then just move the conect call to another method:

```
public class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Init();
    }

    public async void Init(){

        _webService = new OAuthBasedWebService();

        Uri uri=await _webService.Connect();
         _webService_ShowAuthorizationPage(uri);
    }
}


public class OAuthBasedWebService()
{
    private OAuthWrapper _wrapper;

    public async Task<Uri> Connect()
    {
        return await _wrapper.GetAuthorizationUri();

    }
}
```

Comment: The event exists because Connect won't always request an authorization page. If the user is already authorized, for example, no authorization page will be displayed.